# Matrices, determinants, and applications to identities involving Fibonacci numbers

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

### Preamble

It is well known that since: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   F_{n+1} \\
   F_n \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   F_n & F_{n-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

it is valid that:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^n = 
\begin{pmatrix}
   F_{n+1} & F_n \\
   F_n & F_{n-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

By calculating determinants, it immediately follows that:

$$F_{n-1}F_{n+1} - {F_n}^2
=\det\left[\begin{matrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{matrix}\right]
=\det\left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right]^n
=\left(\det\left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right]\right)^n
=(-1)^n$$

or

$$F_{n-1}F_{n+1} - {F_n}^2=(-1)^n$$

This is known as Cassini's identity.

I find both Cassini's identity and this proof exceptionally attractive.

Now, there are other identities that resemble Cassini's identity:

$$F_{n-2}F_{n-1}F_{n+3} - {F_n}^3=(-1)^nF_{n-3}$$

$$F_{n+2}F_{n+1}F_{n-3} - {F_n}^3=(-1)^nF_{n+3}$$

$${F_{n-3}}{F_{n+1}}^2-{F_{n-2}}^2{F_{n+3}}=4 (-1)^n{F_{n}}$$

$${F_{n-1}}^2{F_{n+1}}^2-{F_{n-2}}^2{F_{n+2}}^2=4 (-1)^n{F_{n}}^2$$

$$F_{n-2}F_{n-1}F_{n+1}F_{n+2} - {F_n}^4=-1$$

### Question

> *Is there a proof of five identities above that relies on matrices, the proof that would be attractive and similar to the mentioned proof
>   of Cassini's identity?*
>
> *Also, is there any other Fibonacci identity that follows from a suitable correspondant matrix equation?*

### Trivia

Not directly related to any regular (meaning having the form of an equality) Fibonacci identity, I found also some fairly surprising matrix identities involving Fibonacci numbers, and among them the strangest is:

$$\pmatrix{
3&6&-3&-1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
}^n\pmatrix{
2197&512&125&27\\
512&125&27&8\\
125&27&8&1\\
27&8&1&1
}=\pmatrix{
F_{n+7}^3&F_{n+6}^3&F_{n+5}^3&F_{n+4}^3\\
F_{n+6}^3&F_{n+5}^3&F_{n+4}^3&F_{n+3}^3\\
F_{n+5}^3&F_{n+4}^3&F_{n+3}^3&F_{n+2}^3\\
F_{n+4}^3&F_{n+3}^3&F_{n+2}^3&F_{n+1}^3\\
}
$$

Here, one more unusual fact: $8$, $27$, and $125$ are also cubes of a Fibonacci number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Maybe you can put together an answer? I find this info valuable.

Comment: x @ViviD, comments converted to answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, thanks, it looks great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following statement and proof are interesting:

> Prove that
>
> $$F_{2n-1} = {F_{n}}^2 + {F_{n-1}}^2$$

Let us start with

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^n = 
\begin{pmatrix}
   F_{n+1} & F_n \\
   F_n & F_{n-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If we split $n$ into $p$ and $q$, this can be rewriten as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^p
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^q
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{p+q}
$$

which is actually the same as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
   F_{p+1} & F_{p} \\
   F_{p} & F_{p-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   F_{q+1} & F_{q} \\
   F_{q} & F_{q-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
   F_{p+q+1} & F_{p+q} \\
   F_{p+q} & F_{p+q-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and, by calculating the right bottom element of the right hand side matrix, follows that:

$$F_{p+q-1} = F_p F_q + F_{p-1} F_{q-1}$$

Since we can assume this is valid for any natural $p$ and $q$, it will be valid for $p=q=n$ too:

$$F_{2n-1} = {F_{n}}^2 + {F_{n-1}}^2$$

and this is what we wanted to prove.

---

Moreover, from matrix equation, this is also valid:

$$F_{p+q} = F_{p+1}F_q + F_{p} F_{q-1}$$

and this leads to identity:

$$F_{2n} = F_{n+1}F_n + F_{n} F_{n-1}$$

---

There is also a possibility to split $n$ into $p$, $q$, and $r$, and obtain different identities.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your first identity.  Express everything in terms of $F_{n-1}$ and $F_n$.
$$ \eqalign{F_{n-2} F_{n-1} F_{n+3} - F_{n}^3  &= 3 F_{n}^2 F_{n-1} - F_n F_{n-1}^2 - 2 F_{n-1}^3 - F_{n}^3 \cr
&= (F_n - 2 F_{n-1})(-F_n^2 + F_n F_{n-1} + F_{n-1}^2)\cr
(-1)^n F_{n-3} &= -(-1)^n (F_n - 2 F_{n-1})\cr}$$
so the identity reduces to $F_n^2 - F_n F_{n-1} - F_{n-1}^2 = (-1)^n$
which is equivalent to Cassini.

Comment: Robert, thanks! I appreciate your post! The identity you proved has some "look and feel" of Cassini's one, so you now showed that they are indeed closely related. However, I was hoping for matrix-style proof. I don't know if you have time to try that path?

Answer (score 1):

The "strange matrix identity" at the bottom is just a linear recurrence among the cubed Fibonacci numbers:
$$F_{n+4}^3=3F_{n+3}^3+6F_{n+2}^3-3F_{n+1}^3-F_n^3$$
which looks somewhat less formidable than the matrix equation.

To derive this, we start with Binet's formula
$$ F_n = \frac{\phi^n-(-\phi^{-1})^n)}{\sqrt 5} $$
and cube it to get
$$F_n^3=\frac{(\phi^3)^n-3(-\phi)^n+3(\phi^{-1})^n-(-\phi^{-3})^n}{5\sqrt5}$$
The polynomial whose roots are the numbers raised to the $n$th power here is
$$(x−\phi^3)(x+\phi)(x−\phi^{-1})(x+\phi^{-3})=x^4−3x^3−6x^2+3x+1$$
which supplies the coefficients of the above recurrence.

In a similar way one can derive $$F^2_{n+3}=2F_{n+2}^2+2F_{n+1}^2-F_n^2$$ and its associated matrix form
$$ \begin{pmatrix}2 & 2& -1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^n
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+2}^2\\F_{n+1}^2\\F_n^2\end{pmatrix} $$

See [A055870](http://oeis.org/A055870) for the corresponding coefficients for higher powers of Fibonacci numbers.